# how to view raw json bitcoin transactions

Tags: transactions

Is there any place i can view raw json bitcoin transactions (like [discussed in this tutorial](https://youtu.be/f9nxuhLSyOg?t=5m57s)).

Comment: https://blockchain.info/decode-tx

Comment: ^ Not sure how to use this. How would i use it to view transactions in JSON format?

Comment: paste raw-transaction and press "submit" button

Comment: How do i get the raw-transaction from https://blockchain.info/tx/<tx-id> ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

https://blockchain.info/tx/b657e22827039461a9493ede7bdf55b01579254c1630b0bfc9185ec564fc05ab?format=json

or use `getrawtransaction` and `decoderawtransaction` RPC's in Bitcoin Core.

Answer (score 0):

Or this other website option: http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/getrawtransaction